# Correct way to name UNIQUE, INDEX, FOREING KEYS on LARAVEL 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this code for my migrations on LARAVEL:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('estados', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->primary('PRIMARY');
        $table->string('nombre' , 30)->nullable();
        $table->unique('nombre' , 'nombre_u');
        $table->integer('pais_id')->default('1');
        $table->foreign('pais_id' , 'pais_id_fk')->refereces('id')->on('paises');
        $table->index('pais_id' , 'pais_id_fk_idx');
    });
}
```

How can I improve my code? Idk how to set, for example, the next 2 lines as UNIQUE in the same line:

```
$table->string('nombre' , 30)->nullable();
$table->unique('nombre' , 'nombre_u');
```

Or these 3 lines into only 1 line:

```
$table->integer('pais_id')->default('1');
$table->foreign('pais_id' , 'pais_id_fk')->refereces('id')->on('paises');
$table->index('pais_id' , 'pais_id_fk_idx');
```

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('estados', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->primary('PRIMARY');
        $table->string('nombre' , 30)->unique()->nullable();
        $table->integer('pais_id')->index()->default('1');
        $table->foreign('pais_id')->references('id')->on('paises');
    });
}
```

you don't need to create manual indexes or foreign keys Laravel will take care of that unless you want to.

Comment: this is only another representation of the "normal" sql code, but only a bad one ;)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this is the best way to write it. If your other table is named `pais` then this will work the best:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('estados', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('nombre' , 30)->nullable()->unique();
        $table->foreignId('pais_id')->constrained();
    });
}
```

Otherwise, this is good too...

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('estados', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('nombre' , 30)->nullable()->unique();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('pais_id')->default('1');
        $table->foreign('pais_id')->refereces('id')->on('paises');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use `unsigned()` in `pais_id`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('estados', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->primary('PRIMARY');
        $table->string('nombre' , 30)->unique()->nullable();
        $table->integer('pais_id')->unsigned()->index()->default('1');
    });
    
    Schema::table('estados', function ($table) {
      $table->foreign('pais_id')->references('id')->on('paises');
    });
}
```